# Is their a "region-like" folding feature for Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, folding

I'm developing on Android Studio and as others IDE, Android Studio has a feature to create "regions" in the java code that can be folded. (see below)

With this kind of code

```
//region INITIALIZATION
private int myVaribale;
private String otherVariblae;
//endregion
```

We can fold/unfold the code (see screenshots below).

[image: Unfolded code]

[image: Folded code]

Is their something similar for XML editors (specially the one in Android Studio) ?

Something where we can add for example :

```
<!-- region MY LAYOUTS -->
<RelativeLayout>

   //Some layouts

</RelativeLayout>
<!-- endregion -->
```

Comment: please explain more...

Comment: I updated my question, is it clear enough for you?

Comment: https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18.0/ug-authorEclipse/topics/folding-of-the-xml-elements.html shows it for editing XML in text mode in oXygen.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You **can** now do this:

```
<!--region Title-->
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<!--endregion-->
```

(I'm using Android Studio 3.0 and not sure when it was supported)

Comment: So awesome, I was looking a solution for that feature, and you made my day man! :D

Answer (score 13):

You can simply achieve this by

```
//region name
~~~Code~~~
//endregion
```

Check it out this link for more info. [Create Regions in Android Studio](https://android.jlelse.eu/create-regions-in-android-studio-55333a1ad8a1)

Comment: He asked about XML. This is invalid inside XML...

Comment: it does not work for xml

Comment: yes, it will only work on class level files, not XML files

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut to generate Region/Editor folds.

Or your custom shortcut defined for: `Settings > Keymap > Main Menu > Code > Surround With...`

It works in Kotlin/Java/XML,etc. so you can create folds to Styles/layouts too.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio's XML editor supports only folding on IDE level with `Cmd+Alt+"+" or "-"`.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight code and press ctrl+ "."

Comment: A link to editor shortcut help page would be helpful.